# Nextjs authenticate in a middleware with jwt doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, jwt

In this moment I authenticate user in each API. I want to add a middleware to do it only once.

So I created a file named `_middleware.ts` under `/pages/api` and used the same approach I did for every API.

I have the following code:

**_middleware.ts**

```
import { NextApiRequest } from 'next';
import type { NextFetchEvent, NextRequest } from 'next/server';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { getUserIdOrFail } from './utils/jwt';

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest, ev: NextFetchEvent) {
  const authToken = req.headers.get('Authorization');
  let userId: string;
  try {
    userId = await getUserIdOrFail({
      headers: { authorization: authToken },
    } as NextApiRequest);
  } catch (err) {
    //return 401
  }

  // here usereId might contain the userId if correctly authenticated

  return NextResponse.next();
}
```

**jwt.ts**

```
import { sign, verify } from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { config } from './config';
import { User } from '../models/user';
import { jwtSchema } from './schemas/jwtSchema';
import { NextApiRequest } from 'next';

export const buildJwt = (user: User) =>
  sign({ id: user._id }, config.JWT_KEY, { expiresIn: config.JWT_EXPIRATION });

export const verifyJwt = <T>(jwt: string) => {
  try {
    return verify(jwt, config.JWT_KEY) as T;
  } catch (e) {
    return null;
  }
};

export async function getUserIdOrFail(req: NextApiRequest) {
  const authorizationHeader = req.headers.authorization;
  if (!authorizationHeader || !authorizationHeader.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
    throw new Error();
  }

  const jwt = authorizationHeader.replace('Bearer ', '');
  const parsed = verifyJwt(jwt);

  const { value, error } = jwtSchema.validate(parsed);
  if (error) {
    throw new Error();
  }

  return value.id as string;
}
```

Basically with this code I get the bearer token that server gave to the user when he logged in or registered contained into the `Authorization` header and verify if it is valid. If it is valid I take the userId and use it to do operations with the DB.

***The problem is*** that it does the stuff if I use it in the api files, but in this file it goes into error (catch block with [this error](https://textdoc.co/XWYU45MwGTC1znsy)). Is it a `jsonwebtoken` problem? Should I to do it differently? Or should I leave it in the way it actually is?

Answer (score 3):

The problem with this approach is that the `jasonwebtoken` library uses Dynamic code evaluation which is not allowed into the file `_middleware.ts` in **next.js**. To solve this need to use another library or do it in the api files.